# Remove text that is between two specific characters of a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with data in the following format:

> xxxx(yyyy)

I want to remove what is inside the parentheses, and the parentheses themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can readily cater for multiple replacements in one string with a *Regexp*

```
Sub Test()
Debug.Print CleanStr("xxxx(yyyy)")
Debug.Print CleanStr("and me ()")
Debug.Print CleanStr("and me ()` second string(aaa)")
End Sub
```

*clean string*

```
Function CleanStr(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
   .Pattern = "\([^)]*\)"
   .Global = True
   CleanStr = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a regular expression for this job:

```
Sub DeleteMatches()
  Dim cell As Range, re As Object

  ' define the regular expression to match "(...)"  '
  Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  re.Pattern = "\([^)]*\)"  ' matches "(...)"  '

  ' iterate and clean each cell in range "C2:C100"  '
  For Each cell In Range("C2:C100")
    cell.Value = re.Replace(cell.Value, Empty)
  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1)
```

Comment: Question did ask for VBA.

Comment: @brettdj The question was tagged with vba and excel.  There is no words in the question to denote one over the other.  And the OP may have just assumed that it was only possible with vba.  If the OP where to make the distinction I will happily remove the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub DataGrabber()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
        If InStr(1, r.Value, "(") > 0 Then
            r.Value = Split(r.Value, "(")(0)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim x
x = Split("xxxx(yyyy)", "(")
Dim result
result = x(0)
```

Comment: No it does work correctly. I just tried it again and have it running in excel. Make sure you copied the code correctly.

Comment: I clicked "Run code snippet" above and got `Error: {
  "message": "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 12,
  "colno": 16
}`

Comment: Here is the file uploaded to dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/s636551jagy0rc0/Excel%20Macro%20Split.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: You need to run a check first before using this code to ensure there is a parenthesis, and this would only work on the first occurence, the rest would then be broken down in a way it would be hard to find any other occurences. but good for a single occurence.

Comment: True but it is only a sample to show how a string can be split into arrays very easily. Ubound on the remaining string with ")" and you have your second part. But the example above did not so that's why I provided that code. I have worked with excel files with 1000's of hours of code and I always found splitting strings to be very helpful.